# Can you create a React Native app with IBM Cloud?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have to create an app via IBM Cloud, and the amount of information in IBM Cloud is a bit overwhelming for a beginner. I have two questions:

1) With respect to creating apps, is IBM Cloud just a server where you can host the app?

2) Can I do this with React Native?

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner, you can [get started here](https://www.ibm.com/in-en/cloud/get-started) and move to the next steps based on your use-case/idea

1. IBM Cloud is much more than just a server to host your application. IBM Cloud helps you start building your apps using AI, IoT, data and mobile services.

   *IBM® Cloud® is an open-standards, cloud platform that provides both Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) and Platform as a Service (PaaS) capabilities for building, running, and managing applications. With IBM Cloud, developers can focus on building excellent user experiences with flexible compute options, choice of DevOps tooling, and a powerful set of IBM and third-party APIs and services.*

   To learn more about what IBM Cloud offers, enrol and complete this [course on Cognitiveclass](https://cognitiveclass.ai/courses/ibm-cloud-essentials)

   For beginners, there are app development [starter-kits](https://cloud.ibm.com/developer/appservice/starter-kits) that automatically generate code and also create a new service and add it to your app. You can then deploy the app to various PaaS providers based on your requirement. There is a MERN starter-kit if you are looking for a ReactJS app.
2. There are code-patterns to help you [Build a cross-platform mobile app using React Native](https://developer.ibm.com/patterns/build-a-cross-platform-mobile-app-to-search-company-news-and-gain-insights/). If you are looking at adding mobile push notifications to your React Native app follow [this post](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/implement-push-notifications-in-your-react-native-app-using-ibm-cloud-push-notifications-service)